# How to use design support library together with leanback for android TV?

Tags: android, android-tv, androiddesignsupport, leanback

I have custom designs for android Tv app, not all of them match widgets in leanback library. 
How can I use design support library (for example TabLayout) ? 
It complains I need to use AppCompat theme. 
I am aware that google don't recommend to use tabs on TV.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I wrote my own TabLayout, didn't find a solution to use AppCompat together with leanback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a `TabLayout` in an Leanback app, you can use `ContextThemeWrapper` (I've written this in Kotlin):

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val c = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.Theme_AppCompat)
    return LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.my_tablayout, container, false)
}
```

To get the DPAD working correctly, I subclassed `TabLayout` as follows:

```
class FocusableTabLayout(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): TabLayout(context, attributeSet) {
    override fun focusSearch(focused: View?, direction: Int): View? {
        val view = super.focusSearch(focused, direction)
        if (hasFocus() && view != null) {
            if (direction == View.FOCUS_LEFT) {
                if (selectedTabPosition > 0) {
                    getTabAt(selectedTabPosition - 1)?.select()
                }
            } else if (direction == View.FOCUS_RIGHT) {
                if (selectedTabPosition < tabCount) {
                    getTabAt(selectedTabPosition + 1)?.select()
                }
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    override fun requestFocus(direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?): Boolean {
        val tabStrip = getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
        tabStrip.getChildAt(selectedTabPosition).requestFocus()
        return true
    }
}
```

If you plan to use `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`, then use this subclass to prevent DPAD interactions on one page from triggering a slide:

```
class FocusableViewPager(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet): ViewPager(context, attributeSet) {
    override fun executeKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked for me :) Thank you a lot @tmm1

Answer (score 0):

TabLayout Focus not working with D-PAD (TV App).
I have used  app:tabMode="scrollable" attribute
I have used  without viewpager with 20 tab item.